# Tableviews by NSDate

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nsdate

I have a simple questionnaire app where I need to save the history of surveys displayed by the date when surveys has been taken.  It has to work like this - in tableview user first can see date, after tapping the date he can see answers of the survey. I'll use NSUserDefaults for history.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use `NSUserDefaults`, you could keep all your surveys in `NSMutableDictionary` and your key would be just `NSDate` strings.

Then to get sorted array of surveys you can use the following code:

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [[surveysTaken allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
NSMutableArray *sortedValues = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in sortedKeys)
    [sortedValues addObject: [surveysTaken objectForKey: key]];
```

As a result you will get `sortedValues` array.

Answer (score 0):

- If there is only small amount of data you can use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
- If there is a huge amount of data then you should use [SQLite3](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application) database
- Also you can use [core data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html), which is much more efficient than the other two.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications but It's not exactly what I've been asking. I'm looking for solutions on how to display history surveys displayed by the date when it has been taken.

Comment: @JackMilo: if you are using the database or NSuserDefaults give a field for the time too, then sort the values using NSSortDescriptor or date sorting functions of NSDate class.